# Google admin directory's thumbnailPhotoUrl shows silouette

Tags: google-workspace

I get a list of users of our organization from Google Worksuite's API, via Admin Directory v1 ([API call](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users)).

I want to display the `thumbnailPhotoUrl` on a company website. However, when I include the URL, a silouette is shown. Via network console I can see I get a redirect to the silouette when I embed the URL (via IMG tag) on my website.

When I enter the `thumbnailPhotoUrl` in a browser window (which is logged into Google Worksuite), I *do* get the thumbnail. A private window shows the silouette.

When I look to my own thumbnail, this happens too. However, in the settings I have chosen to m make my thumbnail be shown to everyone (in [Choose what info to show](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6304920?hl=en), I've selected 'visible to anyone').

The website I'm using the profile image on, is protected by a Google login (oauth2) via the same service, so I would expect images with privacy setting of at least "Your organization" to be shown.

So, I'm trying to show profile pictures of all users who have set one.

Is there a way to show these profile images in my own app? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the viewType parameter value (Admin_View or Domain_Public) users.get / users.list methods will either return a public URL or a more private URL of users' the thumbnail photos. Based on your issue descrption the viewType parameter value may be the default ("Admin_view"), please check the viewType parameter value. However based on my experience if the parameter value is "domain_public" also the users.list query needs to follow the scope of "domain_public"